# SQL Server Distributed Availability Group databases not syncing after a Global Primary Replica Failover

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, distributed-availability-groups

> **SQL Server Distributed Availability Group Environment**

AG1 => Node1 (**AG1-Global Primary**) and Node2 (**AG1 - Secondary Replica**)

AG2 => Node3 (**AG2-Forwarder**) and Node4 (**AG2 - Secondary Replica**)

DAGE => Distributed Availability Group Environment

DAGE Availability Replicas => AG1 & AG2

If I failover the Global Primary Role from (**AG1**) Node1 to (**AG1**) Node2, the (DAGE) Distributed Availability Group Replica (AG1) stops synchronizing with the Forwarder (AG2) Replica. (Why?)

When I failback the Global Primary Role from (**AG1**) Node2 back to (**AG1**) Node1,  the (DAGE) Distributed Availability Group Replica (AG1) starts / resumes synchronizing with the Forwarder (AG2) Replica.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to add the [sql-server] tag in addition to your original tag [distributed-availability-groups, and the appropriate version tag, such as [sql-server*-2005*].

Comment: Done, thank you.

Comment: You'd have to dump out the entire configuration, including listeners, mirroring endpoint, etc., which is a lot to ask for rando's in a forum.

Answer (score 1):

**Turns out the above behavior is normal**

- Following a failover to either secondary node on the Primary AG (AG1) or the Primary AG of the secondary AG (AG2)- (**The Forwarder**), the Listener URL ends up pointing to the wrong Primary Availability Group Listener Endpoint URL.
- Reason: After a failover, the Listener IP goes offline on the old Primary and comes online on the new Primary (old Secondary).
- If you noted during the Distributed Availability Group creation process, the Listeners from each Availability Group (AG1 & AG2) make up the Distributed Availability Group Object.
- Unfortunately this information switch is not updated following the failover and the Listener URL is not updated. Thus it remains pointing to an off-lined IP Address.

(The SQL query below displays the Off-Lined Listener URL and Status)

- Run this to determine which URL requires updating (DISCONNECTED  & NOT_HEALTHY)

```
SELECT r.replica_server_name, r.endpoint_url,
rs.connected_state_desc, rs.role_desc, rs.operational_state_desc,
rs.recovery_health_desc,rs.synchronization_health_desc,
r.availability_mode_desc, r.failover_mode_desc
FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states rs
INNER JOIN sys.availability_replicas r
ON rs.replica_id=r.replica_id
ORDER BY r.replica_server_name
```

***AFTER FAILOVER & DDL TO FIX THE ISSUE***

Run this (in the SQLCMD Mode) on the **Global PRIMARY REPLICA** of the Primary **Availability Group 1**

`Availability Group (AG)

`DistAG_NAME - Distributed Availability Group Name

`AG1_GlobalPrimaryReplicaServer` - Primary Replica Server on AG 1

`AG2_GlobalPrimaryReplicaServer` - Primary Replica Server on AG 2

`AG1_Instance1` - Global Primary Replica SQL Server Instance on AG1

`AG2_Instance1` - Global Primary Replica SQL Server Instance on AG2

```
:CONNECT **AG1_GlobalPrimaryReplicaServer\Instance**

USE [master]

GO

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [DistAG_NAME]  
MODIFY AVAILABILITY GROUP ON  
 'AG1' WITH    
    (   
        LISTENER_URL = 'TCP://**AG2_PrimaryReplicaServer**.TESTDOMAIN.COM:PORT'
    )
```

Run this (in the SQLCMD Mode) on the **PRIMARY REPLICA** of the Primary **Availability Group 2**

--Run this on the primary replica of the secondary Availability Group

```
:CONNECT **AG2_GlobalPrimaryReplicaServer\Instance**

USE [master]

GO

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [DistAG_NAME]  
MODIFY AVAILABILITY GROUP ON  
 '**AG2**' WITH    
    (   
        LISTENER_URL = 'TCP://**AG2_PrimaryReplicaServer**.TESTDOMAIN.COM:PORT'
    )
```

To address the issue, Microsoft provided me with this link: [Update Distributed Availability Group Endpoint URL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6988/sql-server-availability-group-maintenance-distributed-availability-groups/), and I found an additional reference, which gives the background details of the setup process: [Setup Distributed Availability Groups](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5053/setup-and-implement-sql-server-2016-always-on-distributed-availability-groups/)

Comment: You should include the salient details from the link directly to your answer, lest it becomes useless when the link goes stale.

Comment: (I will address in subsequent post - very lengthy)

Comment: Added  salient details from the links